How to add up value in column v, by multiplying previous cell with a fixed factor, then add current cell of another column
Starting with a "pd.DataFrame" df :~
         n    v
    0    1  0.0
    1    2  0.0
    2    3  0.0
    3    4  0.0
    4    5  0.0
    5    6  0.0


I'd like to add up value in column "v", whereby a cell in column "v" is produced by multiplying previous cell of "v" with a fixed factor, then add current cell value of column "n". (See sample calculation table below)
    ## sample calculation table :~
    n   v[i]      n  + v[i-1] * fixed factor 
    1   1.0     = 1  + 0.0    * 0.5
    2   2.5     = 2  + 1.0    * 0.5   
    3   4.25    = 3  + 2.5    * 0.5
    4   6.125   = 4  + 4.25   * 0.5
    5   8.0625  = 5  + 6.125  * 0.5
    6  10.03125 = 6  + 8.063  * 0.5

Managed to do it with row-by-row iteration (see for-loop below).
However I think vectorised methods (like cumsum and shift) may be more efficient, but could not figure out how; because cumsum is complicated by multiplication, starting with an empty column v, and need to reference to previous cell of a column.
Wonder how to do this with vectorised methods ?
To reproduce my code :
    df = pd.DataFrame({'n':[1,2,3,4,5,6]})
    df['v'] = 0.0

    def fnv(nu, vu):
        return nu + vu * 0.5

    for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
        df.v.at[i] = fnv(df.n.at[i], df.v.at[i-1] if i>0 else 0.0)

    df (RESULTS) :~
         n      v
    0    1   1.00
    1    2   2.50
    2    3   4.25
    3    4   6.12
    4    5   8.06
    5    6  10.03


Only one answer should be accepted, not both.

I add some performance comparison to my answer.

out of curiosity, what is the maximum length of df? to see if a square matrix approach might be useful

To @jezrael : because both recommended numba, and both pointed out that vectorize methods may not be used. Thanks.

To @mozway: my perceived maximum length would be somewhat less than 3000 rows; and that column "n" would have positive and negative numbers.

That's up to 9M items, a square matrix vectorized approach is technically doable.

Why are none of you convolving?

@DanielF a convolution is a sliding window, this operation is expanding (unless you choose to ignore the old factors)

@mozway at some point you can truncate the window as the weight of 2**-n approaches 0.  Unless you really need to squeeze out every bit of accuracy, and even then you'll hit machine precision at 2**-1100 or so

@DanielF I agree about the truncation on principle, but if you imagine a factor of 0.999 for example instead of 0.5, the decrease won't be negligible even after 3000 "iterations", and should maybe not be ignored.

Then build a kernel as long as the column, it'll still be vectorized.

@DanielF the convolve method gives the intended results. I must admit at this moment it is a little beyond my capability to grasp how it works. I obviously need to study it further.

@mozway : the square matrix method gives the intended results. I must admit I do not fully understand how it works, and I need to do some homework myself.

Since n is variable, you can't easily vectorize this (you could using a matrix operation, see below, but this would take O(n^2) space).
A good tradeoff might be to use numba to speed the operation:
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def fnv(n, factor=0.5):
    out = []
    prev = 0
    for x in n:
        out.append(x + prev*factor)
        prev = out[-1]
    return out

df['v'] = fnv(df['n'].to_numpy())

Output:
   n         v
0  1   1.00000
1  2   2.50000
2  3   4.25000
3  4   6.12500
4  5   8.06250
5  6  10.03125

vectorized approach
You could vectorize using a square matrix:
x = np.arange(len(df))
tmp = x[:, None]-x
df['v'] = np.nansum(np.where(tmp>=0, 0.5**tmp, np.nan) * df['n'].to_numpy(),
                    axis=1)

Intermediates:
# tmp
[[ 0 -1 -2 -3 -4 -5]
 [ 1  0 -1 -2 -3 -4]
 [ 2  1  0 -1 -2 -3]
 [ 3  2  1  0 -1 -2]
 [ 4  3  2  1  0 -1]
 [ 5  4  3  2  1  0]]

# tmp >= 0
[[ True False False False False False]
 [ True  True False False False False]
 [ True  True  True False False False]
 [ True  True  True  True False False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True False]
 [ True  True  True  True  True  True]]

# np.where(tmp>=0, 0.5**tmp, np.nan) * df['n'].to_numpy()
[[1.          nan     nan     nan     nan     nan]
 [0.5     2.          nan     nan     nan     nan]
 [0.25    1.      3.          nan     nan     nan]
 [0.125   0.5     1.5     4.          nan     nan]
 [0.0625  0.25    0.75    2.      5.          nan]
 [0.03125 0.125   0.375   1.      2.5     6.     ]]


Recursive calculations are not vectorisable, for improve performance is used numba:
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def f(a, N):
    d = np.empty(a.shape)
    d[0] = 0
    for i in range(0, a.shape[0]):
        d[i] = a[i] + d[i-1] * N 
    return d

df['v'] = f(df['n'].to_numpy(), 0.5)
print (df)
   n          v
0  1   1.000000
1  2   2.500000
2  3   4.250000
3  4   6.125000
4  5   8.062500
5  6  10.031250
6  7  12.015625

Comparison of solutions, best test in real data:
df = pd.DataFrame({'n':range(1, 1000)})


In [22]: %timeit df['v1'] = f(df['n'].to_numpy(), 0.5)
69.8 µs ± 373 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/79013999/2901002 
In [23]: %timeit df['v2'] = fnv(df['n'].to_numpy())
158 µs ± 2.27 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)


df = pd.DataFrame({'n':range(1, 10000)})


In [25]: %timeit df['v1'] = f(df['n'].to_numpy(), 0.5)
107 µs ± 554 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [26]: %timeit df['v2'] = fnv(df['n'].to_numpy())
860 µs ± 38.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)


You can just convolve the column by a kernel of powers of 0.5, truncating if you hit machine precision:
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

factor = 0.5

kernel = factor ** (np.arange( a.size ) )
kernel = kernel[~np.isclose(kernel, 0)]

out = np.convolve(a, kernel)[ :a.size ]

out
Out[]: array([ 1.,  2.5,  4.25,  6.125,  8.0625, 10.03125])

You'd need to turn the convolution into a pandas function, but it should be fast without resorting to numba

Upvoted since it's a nice idea, but I tested it on 3000 items and for a large factor, this will give a large error

I tried both with monotonous sawtooth functions and monotonically increasing functions with factor = 0.999 and got same results as your function.  What test input did you use?
